# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, connection-timeout

I get this error. And it only begun about a week.

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out! thrown in .

Facebook forum moderators tell me its a hosting providers error.
And hosting providers tell me its a Facebook side error.

I've tried increasing the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10` to 20,60, ...

I'm using the 2.0 version of the SDK.

Comment: If increasing the timeout didn't work maybe you have some kind of problem with the DNS inside your server. Can you check if it resolves facebook URL properly??

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses a Round-Robin DNS and sometimes bad addresses get cached by the client. We have our hosting provider clear the DNS cache, that should fix the problem.